# Error tyring to use loop in javascript, getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to print out the names of each person in the loop.
However I get undefined 3 times.  How can I fix that?

```
var Person = function(name,age){
    self.name = name;
    self.age = age;
};

family = {};
family[0] = new Person("mark", 3);
family[1] = new Person("tom", 12);
family[2] = new Person("michael", 45);
family[3] = new Person("joe", 65);

for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
  member = family[i];    
  console.log(member.name); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `self` keyword in JavaScript. You meant `this`:

```
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this`, not `self` in your `Person` Object.

As a note, you probably want `var` in front of `family`, `i`, and `member`. (unless you want those to be global)

Also, be aware you are setting up an object literal, which is working as a hash, not an array.  Don't know what you intended.

Comment: I tried that, both `[];` and also `new Array;`  Still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this instead of self otherwise the objects wont construct correctly. Also you can use push to add elements to an array instead of using the indexes.

```
var Person = function(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};

family = [];
family.push(new Person("John", 40));
family.push(new Person("Paul", 69));
family.push(new Person("George", 58));
family.push(new Person("Ringo", 71));

for (var i=0; i < family.length; i++) {
  console.log(family[i].name);
}
```